# Back button not working in fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a `MainActivity` and some fragments and am using `WebView` to load some site in all the fragments. Before I wasn't able to go to previous page on press of back button but now I am able to. I have everything working but I can't get a fragment to load on startup. If I add this code in the `MainActivity` to load a fragment automatically, it works but it breaks the back key navigation in other fragments,

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new aboutus())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Is there any other way by which I can load a fragment by default on startup? Here is my `MainActivity` (including the code to open fragment automatically) ,

```
package com.science.s11;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new aboutus())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (aboutus.mWebView!= null) {
        if (aboutus.mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            aboutus.mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }else{
            finish();}
        }
    }

    else if(amp.mWebView!= null){
        if ( amp.mWebView.canGoBack()){
            amp.mWebView.goBack();
        }else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }else{
                finish();}

        }
    }
    else if(ask.mWebView!= null){
        if ( ask.mWebView.canGoBack()){
            ask.mWebView.goBack();
        }else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }else{
                finish();}

        }
    }
    else if(feedback.mWebView!= null){
        if ( feedback.mWebView.canGoBack()){
            feedback.mWebView.goBack();
        }else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }else{
                finish();}

        }
    }
    else if(subscribe.mWebView!= null){
        if ( subscribe.mWebView.canGoBack()){
            subscribe.mWebView.goBack();
        }else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }else{
                finish();}

        }
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_aboutus) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new aboutus())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_amp) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame
                , new amp())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ask) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new ask())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new feedback())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_subscribe) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new subscribe())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample code which I have in all my fragments

```
package com.science.s11;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class aboutus extends Fragment {

public static WebView mWebView;

public ProgressBar progressBar;
public LinearLayout layoutProgress;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aboutus, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.aboutuswebView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    layoutProgress = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


    });




    if (isOnline()) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://science19.com/index.php");
    } else {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/cti.html");
    }
    return v;
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public static boolean canGoBack(){
    return mWebView.canGoBack();
}

public static void goBack(){
    mWebView.goBack();
}



public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
}

}
```

EDIT (added explanation): I actually want to show a fragment on startup of app, the fragment contains WebView. I can do that using this code,

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new aboutus())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

But I even have other fragments and each and everyone has the ability to go back to previous page on back press. Whenever I use this code, I can't go back to previous page on back press on other fragments, it just works in the fragment which is opened using the code, here it is **aboutus**. So, why is this actually happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you add your `Fragment` with `addToBackStack`, it will be stored in the `BackStack` and will be accessed when it is popped from this stack (for example when you press back). Remove the `addToBackStack` and it will stay open - if it is that what you want. If not, please be more specific about your problem & what you want to achieve. :)

Comment: @vinoth12594 it doesn't give any error

Comment: @Amylinn I edited my post with better explanation, hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

With **`AppCompatActivity`** use

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference